# strange issue while reading excel sheet with epplus C#

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

My project has 2 console applications.

First application is writing data to the "first sheet" of an existing excel file (xlsx). The same excel file has a "second sheet" which is pretty huge and is using several formulas which are based on the data of the first sheet.

I am using the following code for writing the data to the first sheet:

```
public void WriteExcel(string InvoiceNo, string InvoiceDate, ...., int rowNumber)
    {
        using (ExcelPackage excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(this.excelFilePath))
        {
            ExcelWorksheet firstWorksheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.First();

            firstWorksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 1].Value = (rowNumber - 2).ToString();
            firstWorksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 2].Value = InvoiceNo;
            firstWorksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 3].Value = InvoiceDate;
            .
            .
            excelPackage.Save();

        }
    }
```

The above code is working completely fine.

Second application is fetching data from the second sheet of this excel file and here I am facing an strange issue.
The application, in the first place, is not picking up the data from the second sheet. But if I am opening the same excel file and closing it after saving it (by pressing Ctrl + S), then the application is fetching data properly.

I am using the following code to fetch the data:

```
string FilePath = @"file path";
foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(FilePath, "*.xlsx"))
            {
                FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);
                ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(fileInfo);
                ExcelWorksheet excelSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[2];
                int colCount = excelSheet.Dimension.End.Column;
                int rowCount = excelSheet.Dimension.End.Row;
                

                for (int col = 7; col < colCount; col++)
                {
                    if (excelSheet.Cells[27, col].Value != "" && excelSheet.Cells[27, col].Value != null && excelSheet.Cells[27, col].Value.ToString() != "NAN")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Data found!.. " + excelSheet.Cells[27, col].Value);
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        
                    }
                }
            }
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: If it's calculating eventually then it's not an issue with your code. You're just manipulating the file. The Excel application calculates the formulas when Excel is running and the file is open. You might want to check whether auto calculate is turned on. If it's off then you have to press F9 to recalculate.

Comment: @ScottHannen ... The auto calculate is already turned on there in excel.

Comment: Sounds like the data you're trying to fetch from the second sheet is not yet calculated when you try to get it. When you open it on Excel manually it calculates, thats why you can get it after that.

Try to calculate the values using EPplus's calculation engine 
https://epplussoftware.com/en/Developers/FormulaCalc